# remote mysql login using username / password not working when adding password to command line

Tags: bash, terminal, mysql

I am running the following command to connect to a remove mysql server (it is part of a bash script that will connect automatically)

`mysql -h slave1 -u monitor -pvP!KnK4*`

And I receive the following response within the terminal window

`-bash: !KnK4: event not found`

When I run `mysql -h slave1 -u monitor -p` without adding the passing in the command line and use the same password when prompted to enter it in this works fine.

What am I doing wrong in this instance?

PS the password above is not the real password (it is much longer just made it smaller for stackexchange purposes)

Comment: apparently bash treats everyting before the ! sign, namely  "pvP" in your case, as options. Try to add a space after "-p". And better don't use the "-p" option on a live server, since the password remains in the bash history and can be stolen

Comment: tried the space and it still doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: did you try quotes?

Comment: characters like ! and * can well be special to bash. So use them in single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use characters that are special to the shell (e. g. `!`, `*`) as a portion of a parameter, you must present it in such a manner as to not be interpreted by the shell before it is passed to the command you're invoking.

Rather than:

```
$ mysql -h slave1 -u monitor -pvP!KnK4*
```

Instead use:

```
$ mysql -h slave1 -u monitor -p'vP!KnK4*'
```

And then, when you have a moment, *change your MySQL user's password if this is your actual password* because you have put it on the internet for all to see.

(As a further aside, you should be aware that anyone who is able to read your user's shell history file also has access to this password.)

Comment: will try that (the pwd itself is different just similar syntax although much longer)

Comment: Glad to hear this is not your actual password.